# Bootstrap width alignment of elements

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I need to arrange an bootstrap input-group and a pill navbar as following:

http://picload.org/image/cwgpppp/bootstrap.png

The input-group should have the width of the navbar which is dynamic and depends on the wording of the navbar. My html structure looks like this:

http://www.bootply.com/efEXkT1CSR

I have no clue how to achieve that. Hope someone can help me!
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility (slightly messy but does work) is to use a combination of `display: inline-box` and `position: absolute`.

1. Wrap the nav and the search group inside another element such as `<header>` (`<div>` will also work).
2. Add `display: inline-box` to `nav` so that it doesn't take up the full width of its parent (`<header>`) but instead fits to the size of its children.
3. Add `position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0;` to `.form-group` (use a custom class here in the real scenario so that it doesn't change other form groups). This will mean that `header` is no longer effected by width of the form group and also will make the form group stretch to the left and right edges of header.
4. Add `position: relative; display: inline-block; padding-top: 40px;` to `header`. The position is so that the form group will be positioned to the header. The display is so that `header` doesn't take up the full width of its parent (`<header>`) but instead fits to the size of its children (in this case `nav`). The padding is because `nav` won't be pushed down by the search group because of the absolute position.

End result should be something like this:

**HTML**

```html
<header>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input class="form-control" id="text" type="text" placeholder="Search ...">
            <span class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">One</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Two</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</header>
```

**CSS**

```css
header {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 40px;
}

.nav {
    display: inline-block;
}

.form-group {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

[Demo on Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/LjBf6eb4va)

Let me know if you have any questions.